# problem creating function with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble with the following code I have written for a form im creating:

The first two lines specify me hiding a field from the user.

The next thing I try to do is create a function that will set fields to a specific value if the StatusGroup field is set to Distance ed.

After the function is written I want it to be called everytime StatusGroup is changed.

And the last line specifies that I want autoSet() called when the page is first loaded.

Any insight as to why the following is not working?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#deliveryinput').css("position", "absolute");
        $('#deliveryinput').css("left", "-9999999");

        var autoSet = function() {
    if($('#StatusGroup').val() == 'Distance Ed') {
        $('#DeliveryGroup').val( 'mail' );
        $('#NVTGC').val('DIST'); }
    else if($('#StatusGroup').val() != 'Distance Ed'){
            $('#DeliveryGroup').val( 'pickup' );}
}


        $('#StatusGroup').change(function() {
            autoSet();
        });

        autoSet();


    });
```

I think you guys nailed the javascript, but I whenever I change StatusGroup the corresponding fields dont respond. Am I using the correct form identifiers? Im comparing the SelectId to its value Distance Ed. And same goes for DeliveryGroup and NVTGC.

```
<label for="StatusGroup">
<span class="field">
span class="<#ERROR name="ERRORStatus">"><b>Status</b></span>
</span>
select id="StatusGroup" name="StatusGroup" size="1" class="f-name" tabindex="4">
<option selected><#PARAM name="StatusGroup"></option>
<option value="Distance Ed">Distance Ed</option>
<option value="Fac/Research">Fac/Research</option>
<option value="Graduate">Graduate</option>
<option value="Undergraduate">Undergraduate</option>
<option value="Staff">Staff</option>
</select><br />
</label>
```

Nevermind! Got it, thank you all :)

Comment: Why was the edit done? The code now won't even parse :(

Comment: Couldn't you just use $('#deliveryinput').hide() instead of the first two lines?

Comment: note: you don't have to wrap the function like `function() {autoSet(); }`, it's simply `autoSet`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Condition should be `if($("#StatusGroup").val() == 'Distance Ed')` otherwise you are just comparing two string and not the status group value.

Fixed:

```
   if($('#StatusGroup').val() == 'Distance Ed') {
       //'DeliveryGroup' = 'mail';
       // assumed you were trying to set the value for a field with id DeliveryGroup
       $('#DeliveryGroup').val('mail');
       $('#NVTGC').val('DIST'); 
    } else if($('#StatusGroup').val() != 'Distance Ed'){
       $('#DeliveryGroup').val('pickup'); 
    }
```

Comment: Closer, but `$('#NVTGC').val() = 'DIST';` doesn't work for assignment.

Comment: @patrick dw so true, i dont know where is my head right now. thanks again

Answer (score 2):

These will never be equal, because they're two different string values:

```
if('#StatusGroup' == 'Distance Ed') {
```

I think you're looking for the value, so do this:

```
if($('#StatusGroup').val() == 'Distance Ed') {
```

...and these won't work at all:

```
'DeliveryGroup' = 'mail';
'NVTGC' = 'DIST';
```

I assume you want selectors for those as well. Just not sure what they should be.

```
$('DeliveryGroup').val( 'mail' );  // replace 'DeliveryGroup' with proper selector
$('NVTGC').val('DIST');            // replace 'NVTGC' with proper selector
```

The two uses of the [`val()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method are such that with no argument, it gets the value. With an argument, it sets the value.

Comment: Hmm, not sure the -1 ... oh, odd. SO glitch?

Comment: i don't think this `$('DeliveryGroup')` will work unless he has a DeliveryGroup tag ;)

Comment: aahhh i seee "replace 'DeliveryGroup' with proper selector"

Answer (score 2):

Your `if` statements are comparing two strings, which are never going to be equal! I think you probably meant to do this:

```
if($('#StatusGroup').val() == 'Distance Ed')
```

Which gets the value of the element with `id` "StatusGroup". I also assume that you don't want to assign the string "mail" to the string "DeliveryGroup", because that's just not possible. Is "DeliveryGroup" a variable? In that case, get rid of the quotes:

```
var DeliveryGroup //This line is somewhere else
DeliveryGroup = 'mail'; //Then you can do this in your if statement
```

As for other issues with your code, you don't need to test the condition again in the `else` branch - if the first condition fails, it will fall through to the `else` branch anyway, so why bother testing again?

You could also hide the `deliveryinput` element with `$('#deliveryinput').hide()` instead of changing the CSS properties.

Answer (score 2):

next to what my predecessors said, your missing the closing bracket of your autoSet function

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum, you're missing the `$().val()` around your selector: `if('#StatusGroup' == 'Distance Ed') {` should be `if($('#StatusGroup').val() == 'Distance Ed') {`

Answer (score 0):

```
var autoSet = function() {
    if ('#StatusGroup' == 'Distance Ed') {
        'DeliveryGroup' = 'mail';
        'NVTGC' = 'DIST'; 
    }
    else if ('#StatusGroup' != 'Distance Ed'){
        'DeliveryGroup' = 'pickup'; 
    }
}
```

Both of your conditions will never be true, so nothing happens in this function.